# What do these characters at the beginning of Tcl lists on multiple lines mean?

Tags: tcl

Excuse me this beginner question: I can't understand these characters at the beginning of Tcl list declarations spanning on multiple lines. Like at the end of the first line of this code snippet:

```
set word_rx {(?x)
          [0-9]+
        | [a-z]+  
        | [a-z]+'[a-z]+
    }
```

I have also seen examples of an ampersand being used there. What do they mean and are there other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regular expression, not anything meant to be treated as a list. The pipes are the usual regular expression alternation operator. Maybe the [expanded syntax](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M94) option is throwing you off?

```
(?x)
  [0-9]+
| [a-z]+  
| [a-z]+'[a-z]+
```

is the same as

```
[0-9]+|[a-z]+|[a-z]+'[a-z]+
```

but more readable because the alternations are split up onto multiple lines.

The [braces](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10), of course, just treat what's in them as literal text so what's in the [brackets](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11) aren't subject to command substitution.

Comment: It was the embedded options sequence at the beginning of the ARE that confused me, but I get it now after having read the documentation page you provided a link to. Thanks.